# How to view print logs for AWS API Gateway V2 Custom Authorizor?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, lambda-authorizer

I have a lambda that is hooked up to my API Gateway to trigger when a `GET /resource` request is made. I validated that this is working before adding the authorizer.

I then added the following authorizer and hooked it up to my API Gateway:
[image]

I can make a request now and I see:

```
{
    "message": "Unauthorized"
}
```

This is expected, but I cannot find logs anywhere to show me what's happening in my authorizer lambda so that I can debug and further implement my authorizer.

I looked around and while there is [access logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference-access-logging-only) that shows some information from API Gateway about the authorization invocation, there isn't anything that will create CloudWatch Logs for the authorizer itself.

I would like to take a peek into what's happening in my authorizer during runtime, how would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that API Gateway requires your identity source to but non-empty, in my case, it was `headers.Authorization`.

If this value is empty, it won't even try to invoke the authorizer, it'll just respond with a `401`.

After providing a value, my authorizer lambda was invoked and a new message was returned (`403`):

```
{
    "message": "Forbidden"
}
```

Note that this is configured to use the simple response payload so a true/false is returned for `isAuthorized`.